# Prove that a subspace contains the span

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let vectors $v, w \in \mathbb{F}^n$. If $U$ is a subspace in $\mathbb{F}^n$ and contains $v, w$, then $U$ contains $\operatorname{Span} \{v,w\}.$

--

My attempt: if $U$ contains vectors $v, w$. Then $v+w \in U$ and $av \in U$, $bw \in U$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{F}$. Since the span is $au+bw$, then $U$ contains the span. I feel like I am missing a step here, but dont know what it is. So, can someone please point it out?

Comment: you've got a good idea, but maybe you are struggling with the terminology a bit. Would you agree that the span of $v,w$ is the set of ALL linear combinations of those two vectors?

Comment: The idea is perfect. I would change some of the words, though (for example: $au\in U$ for **all** $a\in F$, not just some $a\in F$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement Clayton's suggestion, and also replace "Since the span is ..." with:

"Since the sum $av + bw$ is a fully general element of the span, then applying the previous sentence shows that $U$ contains the span."